# Try Catch- Localized Variables

Tags: java

I get a compilation error for running the code below. In the if statement after the try-catch block, the compiler is unable to "resolved to variables." I've initialized these variables already, however. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void Load(UniversityListing uListing, StudentBody sBody) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fIn1= new FileInputStream(filename1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn1));
        existence1 = true;

    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + filename1 +"'");
        existence1 = false;
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filename1+ "'");
        existence1 = false;
    }


    if (existence1 == true){
        LoadUListing(uListing, bufferedReader1,fIn1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Error details

Answer (score 0):

As you are declaring and initializing **fIn1** and **bufferedReader1** inside try block, they will not be accessible outside try.

Try below changes :

```
 public void Load(UniversityListing uListing, StudentBody sBody) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = null;
    FileInputStream fIn1 = null;
    try {
        fIn1 = new FileInputStream(filename1);
        bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn1));
        existence1 = true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + filename1 + "'");
        existence1 = false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filename1 + "'");
        existence1 = false;
    }


    if (existence1 == true) {
        LoadUListing(uListing, bufferedReader1, fIn1);
    }
}
```